# In the case the Zerofunctionselector bug, how to know which function NAME has a 0 selector?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, security, build-from-source

Normally, If a smart contract is not affected by the Zerofunctionselector bug, then at the end of the code which makes jump to the target function lies a `0xfe` opcode (which result in the smart contract execution to `throw`).

But if the opcode is not present, then, the first function in the opcode is executed even if it wasn’t declared `payable`.

How to get actual contract opcode from a deployed address ? How to map those opcodes to source code lines of the contract ?
And can the Zerofunctionselector bug results in private or constructor function to be executed ?

Answer (score 0):

> how to know which function is executed by default from source code?

You can find a good explanation [here](https://etherscan.io/solcbuginfo?a=ZeroFunctionSelector):

> If a function has a selector consisting only of zeros, is payable and
>   part of a contract that does not have a fallback function and at most
>   five external functions in total, this function is called instead of
>   the fallback function if Ether is sent to the contract without data.

Comment: ʏᴇꜱ I ᴋɴᴏᴡ. ʏᴏᴜ ᴅɪᴅ ɴᴏᴛ ᴜɴᴅᴇʀꜱᴛᴏᴏᴅ ᴍʏ ᴁᴜᴇꜱᴛɪᴏɴ : **ᴡʜᴀᴛ I ᴡᴀɴᴛ ɪꜱ ᴛʜᴇ ꜰᴜɴᴄᴛɪᴏɴ ɴᴀᴍᴇ ᴀꜱ ᴡʀɪᴛᴛᴇɴ ɪɴ ᴛʜᴇ ꜱᴏᴜʀᴄᴇ ᴄᴏᴅᴇ !** THIS IS THE COMPILER WHICH DECIDE THIS.